# php - using glob to delete image files along with corresponding db row

Tags: php

I am using the following as a 'delete all' option for users.  Users have images in their account along with a thumbnail of each image.  Each image also has a corresponding row in the database.

It works.  What I am worried about is the fact that new images could be uploaded along with new rows being added to the db 'during' the execution of this script.

So say there is a large amount of images that are now going to be deleted... all the images are deleted in the first loop... now maybe new images have been added during this... now the thumbnail deletion occurs and deletes new thumbnails where its image wasn't deleted in the first pass.  Finally, the rows in the db are deleted... same thing... new entries are deleted and now there is an image and thumb present yet no corresponding entry in the db.  Hopefully that makes sense.

How can I ensure the same data is deleted from all three operations?

```
//delete all screenshots first
$ss_files = glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../user-data/'.$_SESSION['user']['account_id'].'/screenshots/*');

foreach($ss_files as $ss_file)
{
    if(is_file($ss_file))
    {
        unlink($ss_file); // delete file
    }
}

//delete all thumbnails first
$ss_files = glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../user-data/'.$_SESSION['user']['account_id'].'/screenshots/thumbs/*');

foreach($ss_files as $ss_file)
{
    if(is_file($ss_file))
    {
        unlink($ss_file); // delete file
    }
}

//create stmt
$stmt = $db->prepare("
    DELETE del_table.*
    FROM image_logs AS del_table
    INNER JOIN users
        ON users.user_id = del_table.user_id
    INNER JOIN computers
        ON computers.computer_id = users.computer_id            
    WHERE computers.account_id = :account_id
");                     

//add bindings and execute
$binding = array(
    'account_id' => $_SESSION['user']['account_id']
);
$stmt->execute($binding);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I am worried about is the fact that new images could be uploaded along with new rows being added to the db 'during' the execution of this script.

Your current approach is not good. First, if you expect deleting to take more time, then you should perhaps introduce "deleted" flag first. In such case if you want to delete i.e. image, you flag it as `deleted` in DB (same for user account if you need to do more cleaning) and that's it. Done. Deleted. Got some related data to physically remove? Make separate "garbage collector" that will be removing files and deleting cleaned "deleted" records from DB and run it via cron. In such approach, deleting is quick while cleaning leftovers may take longer but it's not a problem.

Also you should not iterate over files in the first place, but over DB records as DB is more important data.

Comment: Makes sense, however, users have a space limit of lets say 1,000 images.  When they delete an image they expect it to delete... thus opening up a 'spot' for a new image.  Having a separate cron in this case would not allow for that functionality... in the sense that if they delete images they would not see the open 'spot(s)' until the next time the cron was run.

Comment: Not sure how optimized this would be, but using your comment... flag all rows in the db as deleted (update statement) then after that has completed run another query which deletes the flagged rows along with their corresponding image files.  First thing that popped in my head...?

Comment: i see no oroblem. image flagged "deleted" does not count to 1000 limit because it is deleted

Comment: Would need to change the logic on how I display their current usage count, but I see what you are saying.  Thanks for a different 'look' on this with your answer!

Comment: If you got your code structured correctly then there shall be a method like `countUserImages()` and this should be the only place you need to alter. If you got raw queries around the code, then it is right moment to refactor your code :)